# transition speed across fragments

Tags: android

I am using fragment  and i have setTransition for the fragment. `fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);`
How to increase the speed of the transition for the fragments?

Answer (score 0):

`setTransition` is for selecting the standard transition animation for the transaction. You can check [setCustomAnimations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) if thats what you need. I have never used that though.